# React-Bootstrap-Typeahead: Using custom input hides selected tokens

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use a custom input and I've copied the example from the [RBT Rendering example](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#rendering). My main goals are to add a test-id to the input, to remove the hint, and to use a custom component for the input. For some reason, when I select an option from the menu, it does not appear in my custom input like in the example. It's clearly set into state as it disappears from the available options. Do I need to wrap something else around my `Form.Control` input?

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-banach-jz41cb?file=/src/App.js), but to avoid link-rot, I'll paste the component code below as well.

```
<Typeahead
  id={`${testIdPrefix}-medal`}
  labelKey="medal"
  multiple
  placeholder="Choose up to 2"
  options={[
    { medal: "Gold" },
    { medal: "Silver" },
    { medal: "Bronze" },
    { medal: "Tin" }
  ]}
  selected={multiSelections}
  onChange={(selections) => setMultiSelections(selections.slice(-2))}
  renderInput={({ inputRef, referenceElementRef, ...inputProps }) => (
    <Form.Control
      test-id={`${testIdPrefix}-medal`}
      {...inputProps}
      ref={(node) => {
        inputRef(node);
        referenceElementRef(node);
      }}
    />
  )}
  renderToken={(option, { onRemove }, index) => (
    <Token
      key={index}
      onRemove={onRemove}
      option={option}
      className="medal-token"
    >
      {`${option.medal}`}
    </Token>
  )}
/>
```

To reproduce:

- Load the sandbox
- Select an option from the menu
- No token will appear (but I expect one to)

Note: this also happens without the custom `Token` but I included it in case that's relevant to the solution. (I need the solution to work with a custom token.)

Comment: Ah, I think the issue is that my `Typeahead` is using `multiple={true}`. Not sure if there will be a way around that then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `multiple={true}` is the issue. `renderToken` is a hook into the built-in multi-selection component to customize token rendering, but won't be called if you use `renderInput`. In that case, you need to handle rendering the selections as tokens yourself.

As a quick example/test, you should be able to simply render the selections below your input in `renderInput`:

```
renderInput={({ inputRef, referenceElementRef, onRemove, selected ...inputProps }) => (
  <>
    <Form.Control
      test-id={`${testIdPrefix}-medal`}
      {...inputProps}
      ref={(node) => {
        inputRef(node);
        referenceElementRef(node);
      }}
    />
    {selected.map((option, idx) => (
      <Token
        key={idx}
        onRemove={onRemove}
        option={option}
        className="medal-token"
      >
        {option.medal}
      </Token>
    ))}
  </>
)}
```